# JSLint gives strange "weird relation" message

Tags: javascript, jslint, boolean-logic

I have some code of the form:

```
function test(a,b,x) {
    return (a > x) !== (b > x);
}
```

This seems like a logical piece of code to me, but JSLint complains with a "Weird relation" message.

So, firstly, does anyone know why JSLint complains? And secondly, is there an option to silence the "Weird relation" error somehow?

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/weird-relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reason JSLInt is seeing the left hand side and the same as the right hand side.

Way to avoid it would be to break it up into variables

```
function test(a, b, x) {
    "use strict";
    var t1 = a > x,
        t2 = b > x;
    return t1 !== t2;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's something I didn't consider... Surely this is not expected behaviour? I'll use your fix, though.

Comment: It is to prevent code like `("foo" === "foo")`, but for some reason it freaks out when ( X > Y) is included on either side. So `( a !== (x > y) )` also triggers it. I just know the fix to get around it since I ran into it in the past, I never searched the code to see what the check was actually doing.

Comment: It seems to be on purpose, so a relation is considered "weird" if either side is itself a relation: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/394bf/jslint.js#L2133

Comment: That's interesting, but annoying. I think my code was much easier to read before applying this fix. Can't agree with Crockford on everything, I guess. Also, the behaviour should be documented.